# How to Get Anonymous Functions to Work With Spark (Scala) from IntelliJ Debug -- Standalone Cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, anonymous-function, spark-submit

I've been Googling this for days.

Big picture: I'm attempting to process XML files from an RDD[String] using any means necessary -- scala-xml, spark-xml, or rolling my own XML handler that's just good enough for a particular XML source. I just switched to Scala and am a little new at it, because Python was becoming horribly inefficient for a Spark program at scale and I'm not ready to just throw more computing power at it.

**First hurdle:** I can't seem to do a basic map function now **and still debug my program in IntelliJ.** I'm trying to do this:

```
val rddOfXMLFiles = sc.wholeTextFiles(folderPathString) // Makes a Tuple2[String, String]
val rddOfXML = rddOfXMLFiles.map(x => x._2) // Gets the second item, the actual XML.
```

When I run it in IntelliJ, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException:
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times,
most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 192.168.28.1):
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sparkxmltest$$anonfun$3
```

(That's all one line, but I wasn't going to make you scroll right for three pages.)

Clearly, the worker isn't getting the compiled code for the anonymous function.

I can see that the compiled code is present in:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\IdeaProjects\sparkxmltest\target\scala-2.11\classes\sparkxmltest$$anonfun$3.class
```

When it builds the jar, I can open it in 7-Zip and see that sparkxmltest$$anonfun$3.class exists in the root of the jar.

Before getting a big cluster, I'm testing with a standalone cluster deployed on my local machine. I've added a folder, C:\sparkjars, to the Path for the system, which is of course the same system the Master and Worker are running on. I added an uber JAR with all encapsulated dependencies to the Project Structure and set it to build on every project build, and I put it in that folder.

I added this to the core program:

```
conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "file:///C:/sparkjars/")
conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "file:///C:/sparkjars/")
```

So here's the entire program:
(Forgive me for a few unnecessary imports; this is testing a small part of a much larger program, and I've weirdly gotten quite far along before hitting this problem.)

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext, sql}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, SQLContext, SparkSession}
import com.databricks.spark.xml
import com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlReader
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

import scala.io.Source
// import scala.util.matching.Regex
// import java.io.File
import java.nio.file

object sparkxmltest {
  var LastTimeStamp = System.nanoTime()

  def cheapoBenchmark() : Long = {
    val previousTimeStamp = LastTimeStamp
    LastTimeStamp = System.nanoTime()
    LastTimeStamp - previousTimeStamp
  }

  def safeArrayIndex(a: Array[String], i: Int): Option[String] = {
    try Some(a(i)) catch { case _: Throwable => None }
  }

  def getSecondElement(insies: Tuple2[String, String]) : String = {
    insies._2
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val ipAddress = safeArrayIndex(args, 0).getOrElse("0.0.0.0")
    val folderPathString = safeArrayIndex(args, 1).getOrElse("file:///C:/sparkwarehouse")
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName("Test XML")
    conf.setMaster(s"spark://$ipAddress:7077")
    conf.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/sparkwarehouse/")
    conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "file:///C:/sparkjars/")
    conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "file:///C:/sparkjars/")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()
    val sqlCtx = spark.sqlContext

    val rddOfXMLFiles = sc.wholeTextFiles(folderPathString)
    val rddOfXML = rddOfXMLFiles.map(x => x._2)
    println("Input Text:")
    rddOfXML.collect().foreach(println)

    // val df = new XmlReader().xmlRdd(sqlCtx, rddOfXML)
    println("End")
  }
}
```

And here's the build:

```
name := "sparkxmltest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0" % "compile"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-xml_2.11" % "0.4.1"
```

Now, I can't be the first person who's ever tried to map an RDD with an anonymous function. How do I get the Workers to have access to the anonymous function?

Spark-Submit does seem to solve that (finally), but I can't get anything useful from STDOUT.

(One other annoying detail: I can't spark-submit without getting certificate errors, until I open the resulting JAR in 7-Zip and delete META-INF\DUMMY.SF . It gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

That took me a couple hours to deduce from Internet posts. But I don't know how to make SBT stop automatically including that certificate file.)

**It does work when I spark-submit.** I suppose any successful run is good enough. But you can probably understand why this workflow makes prototyping and testing difficult.

**It does work when I set master: local[*]** But the point of what I'm doing is not just to make my Spark script run on a single local machine. Just like Spark-Submit, I suppose that does prove that the dependencies in the project are OK. (You wouldn't believe how long I spent learning how to / that I even had to check my version dependencies on mavenrepository ... but like I said, I'm a n00b. For the sake of those who may follow: If you're using a Spark standalone cluster, make sure the version installed in the cluster matches the version you're using in your program, that the version of Scala you're using matches the version Spark is built for, that particular version of Scala is installed and on  Path, that Spark-Core version matches the version that's a dependency of other libraries you're using such as Spark-XML, Spark-SQL, etc. Start with the least dependent module you're using and work backwards.)

Long story short, it all works together. Now I'm being unnecessarily particular. For rapid testing purposes, how can I make sure my built project is available on all the Workers' classpaths without using Spark-Submit, i.e., do it from within the Scala program itself? It's probably an option within SparkConf. I should be able to make IntelliJ spit out an uber-JAR into a public folder as part of the build. If I could then add it to the workers' classpath from within the Scala program, then that would mean I could do rapid testing and debugging from within IntelliJ.

If I'm using a larger cluster, I think there's a "jars" option that will make the Master distribute the JARs I just built to the Workers. But they still need to go on the classpath when they get there -- how do I know what the path should be, based on where the JARs will get stored on the Workers?

So can anyone tell me (and everyone else trying to do the same thing) how I can efficiently build the project and deploy it in such a way that I can subsequently debug from within IntelliJ?

Comment: did you try to use a local master instead of standalone master?

Comment: I did. (As suggested, did an Edit of the original post to reflect that additional piece of info.)

Comment: So the short answer is: Build a JAR. Get my JAR on the classpath. The longer answer is: How? (There are clearly ways to do it with spark-submit , but then I lose the ability to debug in IntelliJ.) Is there a command-line I can use when starting the cluster, or more ideally, a configuration I can use in my spark-conf, to tell it to load my JAR?